# make a post from ajax to controller (Spring security)

Tags: ajax, spring, security, spring-mvc, controller

Hi have a problem have an error

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported
```

when im trying to make post on controller. I think the problem is in Spring Security, I have add it in my project. before it worked well.

```
  <form  id="estimationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4><i class="fa fa-address-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 평가</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Estimate modal -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-block" placeholder="이름" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-block" placeholder="이메일" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                        <textarea class="form-control form-block" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="아이디" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <!-- Estimate modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">닫기</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="estimate()" class="btn btn-primary">보내기</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

here is my js `function estimate() {

```
var loginForm = document.forms["estimationForm"];
var name = loginForm.name.value;
var email = loginForm.email.value;
var message = loginForm.message.value;
alert(name +" " + email + " " + message);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: name , email: email , message: message},
    url: "estimate",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.url == "ok") {
            alert("message have been sent")
        } else if (data.url == ""){
            alert("fail")
        }
    },
});
```

}`

and here is my controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class IndexPageController {



    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Locale locale, Model model) {

    /*  // add parametrized message from controller
        String welcome = messageSource.getMessage("welcome.message", new Object[]{"John Doe"}, locale);
        model.addAttribute("message", welcome);*/

        // obtain locale from LocaleContextHolder
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        model.addAttribute("locale", currentLocale);


        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "index";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/estimate" ,  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String estimateWindow(@RequestParam("name") String recipientName, @RequestParam("email") String recipientMail,  @RequestParam("message") String recipientRequestText, Model model) {



        System.out.print("name " + recipientName + " email " + recipientMail + " text " + recipientRequestText);

        JSONObject myJsonObj = new JSONObject();

        myJsonObj.append("response", "ok");
        return myJsonObj.toString();
    }


    /**
     * This method returns true if users is already authenticated [logged-in], else false.
     */
    private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Crsf as i mentioned. i have did like in this guide.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

and now ajax making POST on /estimate controller

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX function is attempting to POST to /login, which your controller has defined as a GET method.

Try changing your login method to POST, or create another login endpoint to handle the POST.

Comment: in my ajax the url is estimate and im trying to send data to /estimate method in controller. The problem is when i make post without ajax, only jsp form and submit - it working well. The problem i think is in crsf token, but i dont know how to write it.

Comment: I have in form   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Comment: maybe i have to send csrf token through ajax. But i dont know how.

Comment: The error that you're getting is not caused by lacking the CSRF token, it is caused because you're not posting to the correct URL.  Try adding more debug information to your JS function, just outputting _fail_ is not going to help much.  I'd start with looking at your URL, which is now _estimate_, should this be _/estimate_?